# divisor for std_logic_vector VHDL

Tags: vhdl, greatest-common-divisor, ghdl

I try to implement a divisor for `std_logic_vector` with the language `VHDL`. 
After I have implemented it, I have to use GHDL but encountered this error :

```
vhdl:error: bound check failure at divisor.vhdl
```

It's correspond to this :

```
else ....
nb_reg <= (2*nb);
```

My code is :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity div is 
    generic 
    (
        DATA_WIDTH : natural := 8;
        ADDR_WIDTH : natural := 3
    );

    port (
        clk     : in std_logic;
        reset   : in std_logic;
        raddr   : in natural range 0 to 2**ADDR_WIDTH - 1;
        waddr   : in natural range 0 to 2**ADDR_WIDTH - 1;
        max     : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH -1) downto 0);
        data    : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH -1) downto 0);
        q       : out std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH -1) downto 0)

        );

end div;

architecture rtl of div is

    -- Build a 2-D array type for the RAM
    subtype word_t is unsigned((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
    type memory_t is array(natural range <>) of word_t;

    -- Declare the RAM signal.  
    signal ram, div : memory_t((2**ADDR_WIDTH)-1 downto 0);

    -- Declare the n and max_reg signal.    
    signal n,m : unsigned(((2*DATA_WIDTH)-1) downto 0);
    signal max_reg : unsigned(((2*DATA_WIDTH)-1) downto 0);
    signal nb : unsigned(((2*DATA_WIDTH)-1) downto 0);
    signal nb_reg : unsigned(((4*DATA_WIDTH)-3) downto 0);

    -- Build div_reg, ram_reg
    type memory_reg is array(natural range <>) of unsigned(((2*DATA_WIDTH)-1) downto 0);

    signal ram_reg: memory_reg((2**ADDR_WIDTH)-1 downto 0);

begin
    process(clk,reset)
    begin 
    if (reset = '1') then 
            ram(waddr) <= X"00";
            div(waddr) <= X"00";
            max_reg <= X"0000";
            ram_reg(waddr) <= X"0000";
            n <= X"0000";
            nb <= X"0000";
            --nb_reg(((4*DATA_WIDTH)-3) downto 0) <= "0";
            m <= X"0000";
    elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then 
        ram(waddr) <= unsigned(data);
        max_reg((DATA_WIDTH -1) downto 0) <= unsigned(max);
        ram_reg(waddr)((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0) <= ram(waddr)((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
        nb <= (nb+1);
        if (ram(waddr) = max_reg)then 
            div(waddr) <= div(waddr)+1;
        elsif (ram(waddr) > max_reg)then
            while ((div(waddr)*(ram(waddr)) > max_reg) or (m <(DATA_WIDTH -1))) loop
                div(waddr) <= (div(waddr))+1;
                max_reg <= (max_reg) - (ram_reg(waddr));
                m <= m+1; 
            end loop;
            m <= (m-1);
            while (((div(waddr)*ram_reg(waddr)) < max_reg-1) or (n <(DATA_WIDTH)-(m))) loop
                ram_reg(waddr)(((2*DATA_WIDTH)-1) downto 1) <= ram_reg(waddr)(((2*DATA_WIDTH)-2) downto 0);
                ram_reg(waddr)(0) <= '0';
                n <= n+1; 
                nb_reg <= (nb*2);
                nb(((2*DATA_WIDTH)-1) downto 0) <= nb_reg(((2*DATA_WIDTH)-1) downto 0);
            end loop;
            ram_reg(waddr) <= ram_reg(waddr) - (max_reg);
            div(waddr) <= (div(waddr))+(1/(nb));
        else 
            while (((div(waddr)*ram_reg(waddr)) < max_reg-1) or (n <(DATA_WIDTH)-(m))) loop
                ram_reg(waddr)(((2*DATA_WIDTH)-1) downto 1) <= ram_reg(waddr)(((2*DATA_WIDTH)-2) downto 0);
                ram_reg(waddr)(0) <= '0';
                n <= n+1; 
                nb_reg <= (2*nb);
                nb(((2*DATA_WIDTH)-1) downto 0) <= nb_reg(((2*DATA_WIDTH)-1) downto 0);
            end loop;
            ram_reg(waddr) <= ram_reg(waddr) - (max_reg);
            div(waddr) <= (div(waddr))+(1/(nb));
        end if;
    else null;
    end if;

    end process;

    q <= std_logic_vector(div(waddr));

end rtl;
```

The test bench :

```
-- descrizione del Test_bench
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity div_tb is
end div_tb;

architecture behaviour of div_tb is

--dichiarazione dei COMPONENT ovvero la Unit Under Test
component div is

    generic 
    (
        DATA_WIDTH : natural := 8;
        ADDR_WIDTH : natural := 3
    );

    port 
    (
        clk     : in std_logic;
        reset   : in std_logic;
        raddr   : in natural range 0 to 2**ADDR_WIDTH - 1;
        waddr   : in natural range 0 to 2**ADDR_WIDTH - 1;
        max     : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH -1) downto 0);
        data    : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH -1) downto 0);
        q       : out std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH -1) downto 0)
    );
end component;

-- Clock period definitions
constant clk_period : time := 1 us; 

constant DATA_WIDTH : natural := 8;
constant ADDR_WIDTH : natural := 3;
signal CLK_tb: std_logic := '0';
signal RESET_tb: std_logic := '1';
signal raddr_tb, waddr_tb : natural range 0 to 2**ADDR_WIDTH - 1;
signal data_tb, q_tb, max_tb : std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH -1) downto 0);

signal I : integer := 0; -- variabile per il conteggio dei clock

begin
        clk_process: process --processo di generazione del CLK
        begin
            CLK_tb <= '0';
            wait for clk_period/2;
            CLK_tb <= '1';
            wait for clk_period/2;
            I<=I+1;

            if I=200 then wait; -- durata della simulazione: 30 colpi di CLK
            else null;
            end if;

        end process;

    -- istanziazione della Unit Under Test
    UUT: div    generic map (ADDR_WIDTH => 3, DATA_WIDTH => 8)
                port map (clk=>clk_tb, reset=>RESET_tb, raddr => raddr_tb, waddr => waddr_tb , data => data_tb, q => q_tb, max => max_tb);  

    stimoli: process
    begin       
        RESET_tb <= '1';
        wait for clk_period*3;
        RESET_tb <= '0';
        wait;       
    end process;


    we: process
    begin       
        max_tb <= "11100110";
        wait;       
    end process;

    Data : process
    begin   
        data_tb <= "00000000"; raddr_tb <= 0; waddr_tb <= 0; wait for clk_period*3;
        data_tb <= "01010110"; raddr_tb <= 1; waddr_tb <= 1; wait for clk_period*8; 
        data_tb <= "01000110"; raddr_tb <= 2; waddr_tb <= 2; wait for clk_period*8; 
        data_tb <= "11001110"; raddr_tb <= 3; waddr_tb <= 3; wait for clk_period*8; 
        data_tb <= "01000111"; raddr_tb <= 4; waddr_tb <= 4; wait for clk_period*8;
        data_tb <= "11100110"; raddr_tb <= 5; waddr_tb <= 5; wait for clk_period*8; 
        data_tb <= "01000110"; raddr_tb <= 6; waddr_tb <= 6; wait for clk_period*8; 
        data_tb <= "01010110"; raddr_tb <= 7; waddr_tb <= 7; wait for clk_period*8; 
        wait;
    end process;

end behaviour;
```

I use the `2007` version of GHDL and it is not possible for me to update, my teacher wants me to use this one.

Could somebody help me with this code?

Comment: Please can you paste the error message into the question as text rather than an image. External links have a habit or breaking.

Comment: Which is line 81?

Comment: It is in the else :
nb <= std_logic_vector(2*unsigned(nb));

Comment: Suggestion: create intermediary signals that are unsigned rather than converting to/from std_logic_vector over and over.  This makes the code horribly unreadable.

Comment: bound check errors occur during simulation noting your code analyzes. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a testbench) allowing the error to be reproduced. Matthew's answer shows an assignment on line 83 with the library declaration appearing on line 1. The nb assignment statement on line 74 would cause a similar bounds check error (`nb <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(nb)*2);`).

Comment: This code is impossible to read. And very hard to debug, as you are using while-loops with many-many-many assignments within a clock cycle.

Comment: What you also seem to forget, is that a signal assignment is not applied to the signal until the next delta cycle. I.e. signals don't change _within a process_ --> **they will only change after the process is finished**. So `ram(waddr) <= data;` followed by `if (ram(waddr) = max) then` will not be the same as `if (data = max) then`. The old value of `ram(waddr)` will instead be evaluated in the if-statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am sorry if my code is not clear :/
JHBonarius, what are you suggested to me to do?

Comment: Start by not using `std_logic_vector` internally, but just use the `unsigned` type for the signals. Then drop the while loops: just do one assignment per clock cycle, and control using a finite state machine. By the way: a) what kind of data are you dividing? Integer or fixed-point? b) do you want to write synthesizable code?

Comment: I don't understand how it is supposed to work if the while loop are not there. There are used to repeating what I have to put to remplace? 
Could you give me an example?
I want to divided std_logic_vector data by the max of them, at the end I have the quotient of data / max.
Yes, my write have to be synthetisable.

Comment: I'm afraid you seem to be missing the basic concepts of computer arithmetic and FPGA design. You should start to think in terms of register transfer level and include delays. Then you will for instance realize that its not possible to perform a division in one clock cycle. [Unless you have a lot of resources (LUTs) and time (low clock frequency)]. Please look up what a finite state machine is, and how it can help you to control your algorithm.

Comment: I am already not  manage to make this work, I will not put delay to complicate my code.

Comment: First, my teacher wants to implement only like this without delay...

Comment: You don't seem to understand me. I'm referring to actual delay inside the FPGA. Not delay statements in the VHDL. Delay statements will not even be synthesizable. The `while` loops you are using show you want to program VHDL like you would do for a CPU in C(++) Matlab or Python for instance. But that's not how HDLs work.

Comment: And so, How I can do without a while? 
Like I said, my problem is not to be synthetisable. I just want that program works with GHDL, for the moment.
You only say me things that are not answer to my question. Why I have a problem with nb_reg <= (2*nb)   ?

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication operator in the `numeric_std` package is defined thus for multiplying a `natural` by an `unsigned`:

```
  -- Id: A.18
  function "*" (L: NATURAL; R: UNSIGNED) return UNSIGNED;
  -- Result subtype: UNSIGNED((R'LENGTH+R'LENGTH-1) downto 0)
  -- Result: Multiplies an UNSIGNED vector, R, with a nonnegative
  --         INTEGER, L. L is converted to an UNSIGNED vector of
  --         SIZE R'LENGTH before multiplication.
```

As you can see, the output is twice the width of the `unsigned` argument minus 1. In this line

```
nb <= std_logic_vector(2*unsigned(nb));
```

you are assigning the result back to the `unsigned` operand, which obviously is not a different width to itself.

So, you either need an intermediate variable of the right width or perhaps a shift left?